# url returns no response - spring boot

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I am following a small exercice on REST services.

I work with spring 2.0.3.RELEASE and tomcat 7.

Issue: Urls of the application return nothing

The controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/persons")
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    PersonService ps;

    @RequestMapping("/all")
    public List<Person> getAll() {
        return ps.getAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping("{id}")
    public Person getPerson(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        return ps.getPerson(id);
    }
}
```

Here is the class PersonService

```
@Service
public class PersonService {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    PersonRepositoryInterface personRepository;
    public PersonService()
    {

    }

    public Person getPerson(Long id)
    {
        return personRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    public List<Person>getAll()
    {
        return (ArrayList<Person>) personRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Here is the interface PersonRepositoryInterface

```
public interface PersonRepositoryInterface extends CrudRepository<Person,Long> {

    List<Person>findByAge(int Age);
    List<Person>findByFirstName(String firstname);
    @Query(" from Person p where p.id=:x")
    public Person findOne(@Param("x") Long id);

}
```

The class person has as attributes the field id, firstName, lastName.

Of course , There are some records in the database and there is no errors when running the code

The end of the log generated. There is no issue with the DB connection

```
Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
Started WebservicesApplication in 8.93 seconds (JVM running for 9.89)
Application shutdown requested.
Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@1afa13b: startup date [Thu Aug 02 22:22:40 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
 Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
 Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
 HHH000031: Closing
 External cascade style registration [persist : STYLE_PERSIST] overrode base registration [STYLE_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY]
 Implicitly destroying ServiceRegistry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
 Implicitly destroying Boot-strap registry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
 HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
 HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Comment: Does your DB connection work correctly? Also the logs would help us to solve the problem ;-)

Comment: Please also paste what URL are you trying to read from.

Comment: I am testing this url: 
`http://localhost:8080/persons/all`

Comment: The connection DB works well. no issue. It will be difficult to post all the logs here lol